# How can I create a services in Capella and call it in my M2DOC Word document?

Tags: eclipse, acceleo, m2doc

How can I create a services in Capella and call it in my M2DOC Word document?

I want, for example, create a services for print a functional tree, and use this code in many different documents without re-write every time the code.

Thank you a lot.

Stefania

Answer (score 0):

It seems this section of the documentation explains what you want to do: https://www.m2doc.org/ref-doc/nightly/index.html#providing-new-services